# XPath Evaluation searching in complete document only

Tags: xpath

I am facing an issue where XPath evaluate is working on complete Document only, instead of individual nodes. My`xml is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<RuleConfiguration>
    <Name>RDG1</Name>
    <IsActivated>Y</IsActivated>
    <ColorCode>#FF0000</ColorCode>
    <HaltAppIfRuleMet>Y</HaltAppIfRuleMet>
    <Parameters>
        <Parameter>
            <ParameterName>CompareToBalance</ParameterName>
            <ParameterValue>0.0</ParameterValue>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter>
            <ParameterName>FONDEP</ParameterName>
            <ParameterValue>520</ParameterValue>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter>
            <ParameterName>RDG1Counter1</ParameterName>
            <ParameterValue>1</ParameterValue>
        </Parameter>
    </Parameters>
    <Descriptions>
        <Description>
            <LocaleCode>en_US</LocaleCode>
            <LocaleText>The customer has 3 or more active accounts outside FONDEP</LocaleText>
        </Description>
        <Description>
            <LocaleCode>fr_FR</LocaleCode>
            <LocaleText>The customer has 3 or more active accounts outside FONDEP</LocaleText>
        </Description>
    </Descriptions>
</RuleConfiguration>
<!--  Rule no 2  -->
<RuleConfiguration>
    <Name>RDG2</Name>
    <IsActivated>Y</IsActivated>
    <ColorCode>#FF0000</ColorCode>
    <HaltAppIfRuleMet>Y</HaltAppIfRuleMet>
    <Parameters>
        <Parameter>
            <ParameterName>CompareToBalance_ahBal</ParameterName>
            <ParameterValue>0.0</ParameterValue>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter>
            <ParameterName>CompareToBalance_ahBalArr</ParameterName>
            <ParameterValue>0.0</ParameterValue>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter>
            <ParameterName>FONDEP</ParameterName>
            <ParameterValue>520</ParameterValue>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter>
            <ParameterName>RDG2Counter1</ParameterName>
            <ParameterValue>2</ParameterValue>
        </Parameter>
        <Parameter>
            <ParameterName>RDG2Counter2</ParameterName>
            <ParameterValue>1</ParameterValue>
        </Parameter>
    </Parameters>
    <Descriptions>
        <Description>
            <LocaleCode>en_US</LocaleCode>
            <LocaleText>The customer has 3 or more active accounts outside FONDEP</LocaleText>
        </Description>
        <Description>
            <LocaleCode>fr_FR</LocaleCode>
            <LocaleText>The customer has 3 or more active accounts outside FONDEP</LocaleText>
        </Description>
    </Descriptions>
</RuleConfiguration>
```

And my code is:

```java
XPath resXPTraverse = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String strRuleConfigPath = "/RuleConfigurations/RuleConfiguration";
NodeList nlRuleNodeList = (NodeList)resXPTraverse.compile(strRuleConfigPath).evaluate(ExpConfigXML, XPathConstants.NODESET); 
System.out.println("/RuleConfigurations/RuleConfigurationlength>>>"+nlRuleNodeList.getLength()); //returning length 2 correct
String strDescriptionsPath = strRuleConfigPath+"/Descriptions/Description";
NodeList nlDescriptionsList = (NodeList) resXPTraverse.compile(strDescriptionsPath).evaluate(nlRuleNodeList.item(0), XPathConstants.NODESET);
System.out.println("/Descriptions/Description length>>>"+nlDescriptionsList.getLength()); //returning length 4 instead of 2
```

I am trying to fetch the  tag of first node only, but it is searching in the complete XML Document and returning with length 4.
Kindly help me here.

Answer (score 0):

Evaluating `strRuleConfigPath+"/Descriptions/Description"` means evaluating
`/RuleConfigurations/RuleConfiguration/Descriptions/Description`. There exist 4 different paths with the expression you provide.

You need to evaluate:
`"/RuleConfigurations/RuleConfiguration[1]/Descriptions/Description"`